# Spring Boot + Liquibase - NotWritablePropertyException during startup

Tags: spring, spring-boot, liquibase

I'm using `springBootVersion = '1.5.8.RELEASE'` and added to my build.gradle (Spring manages version):

```
compile('org.liquibase:liquibase-core')
```

Here is my resources folder:

[image: resources]

And my application.yml:

```
liquibase:
  change-log: classpath:db/changelog.xml
  default-schema: public
  enabled: true
  url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/exampledb
  user: postgres
  password: postgres
```

I have more stuff in both of those but I'm quite sure they shouldn't be a problem.
Here is the exception I'm getting when starting up my application after I've added liquibase-connected stuff:

```
    2018-04-24 14:17:58.305  WARN 28440 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseProperties': Could not bind properties to LiquibaseProperties (prefix=liquibase, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=false, ignoreNestedProperties=false); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'domain[package]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseProperties]: Cannot access indexed value in property referenced in indexed property path 'domain[package]'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'domain[package]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseProperties]: Bean property 'domain[package]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
2018-04-24 14:17:58.306 DEBUG 28440 --- [  restartedMain] o.k.a.s.f.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter   : Unregistering deployment
2018-04-24 14:17:58.309  INFO 28440 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-04-24 14:17:58.328  INFO 28440 --- [  restartedMain] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-04-24 14:17:58.335 ERROR 28440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseProperties': Could not bind properties to LiquibaseProperties (prefix=liquibase, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=false, ignoreNestedProperties=false); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'domain[package]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseProperties]: Cannot access indexed value in property referenced in indexed property path 'domain[package]'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'domain[package]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseProperties]: Bean property 'domain[package]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:372)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at com.onwelo.vendormanagement.VendorManagementApplication.main(VendorManagementApplication.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseProperties': Could not bind properties to LiquibaseProperties (prefix=liquibase, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=false, ignoreNestedProperties=false); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'domain[package]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseProperties]: Cannot access indexed value in property referenced in indexed property path 'domain[package]'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'domain[package]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseProperties]: Bean property 'domain[package]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'domain[package]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseProperties]: Cannot access indexed value in property referenced in indexed property path 'domain[package]'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'domain[package]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseProperties]: Bean property 'domain[package]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyHoldingValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:403)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.processKeyedProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:278)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder$RelaxedBeanWrapper.setPropertyValue(RelaxedDataBinder.java:699)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.applyPropertyValues(DataBinder.java:859)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.doBind(DataBinder.java:755)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.doBind(RelaxedDataBinder.java:128)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.bind(DataBinder.java:740)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.doBindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:272)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.bindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:240)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:329)
    ... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'domain[package]' of bean class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseProperties]: Bean property 'domain[package]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:631)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyHoldingValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:400)
    ... 61 common frames omitted
```

Comment: dont you have any other property file or env variable that has key `domain[package]` or `domain` ? It mut come from somewhere.

Comment: Searched whole project for "domain[package]" and nothing came up

Comment: Something doesn't seem right with the package name of the LiquibaseProperties class being used. Yours starts with "liquibase-org.springframework.boot...". Mine starts with "org.springframework.boot...". I have the same dependency of "org.liquibase:liquibase-core" in my build.gradle.